Mutually incompatible MagLev standards?
As magnetic levitation (MagLev) train systems have been developed since the 1980s, I have a question of
What standards used in MagLev train systems would make two MagLev lines mutually incompatible?
In a story I'm currently writing, two neighbouring countries decide to connect their MagLev train lines, which both countries use widely. But soon, it becomes clear that each country has its own set of standards for their MagLev lines, and they are mutually incompatible thus making it impossible to connect both systems without one or both countries completely rebuilding their MagLev train network. As the story involves the protagonist, an ambassador of one country to another, facilitating both governments working together to find a solution, I would like to include realistic technical details.

Ask on worldbuilding. Think along the lines of what makes European and australian outlets incompatible? Same principles apply.

What about voltages between countries? What justifies each choice? Trade relationships? Previous conquerors? What did Germany consider for theirs compared to Japan with the one they built?

@SolarMike What would voltage difference mean for MagLev? Would a train requiring higher voltage be incapable of keeping levitating on a lower voltage line? Higher voltage blowing fuses of a train requiring lower voltage and rendering it inoperable?

Have you researched how much power needs to be delivered to the maglev train? Have you checked how some of the tracks work to improve efficiency?

@SolarMike I have researched general principles and a few notable real-world examples. I lack the competence to examine details. I know just enough about electricity to fix a lamp at my home while avoiding electrocution.

The most likely issue will be track (and vehicle) dimensions - rather similar to change of railway gauge between France and Spain and Europe to Russia. Sometimes done to reduce railway usefulness for invasion. On maglev this will be far more complex with shape of "carriage", distance between armature poles, signaling systems, points / switches, structure gauge (tunnel and platform clearance). All sorts of things. "But soon, it becomes clear ..." It would always have been obvious to anyone with any knowledge.
